# How to move "master" of gitfow to initial commit

Tags: git

I have 5 commits in my project , then i initialize GITFLOW using sourcetree , i got a problem because the "Master" branch located at the 5th commit instead of the 1st commit , (which is pod file related one). I wonder how to include the previous 4 commits as "Master" ??

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

5 has a "master" tag

1 ~ 4 has nothing but "HEAD"

Comment: All five of your commits are against `master`; the fifth commit just indicates the *current* state of `master`; `master` includes all five commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fifth commit is your most recent one, then you are good to go.

`git log` should show you all your work up to the fifth commit.